# how to render bootstrap alert

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How would you render Twitter Bootstrap alert? Suppose that for an app there is only one alert container / flash message.

I'd like it to appear when there is an error. Now I use a very dirty solution, adding presence to the controller.

```
Sks.KudoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['currentUser']
  addKudo: (user) ->
    self = this
    token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    ErrorMessageTmplt = """
      <div id="kudos-flash" class="alert" alert-error" style="display: none">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        <strong>oops! an error occured!</strong>
      </div>
    """
    $flashContainer = jQuery '#flash-container'

    jQuery.post("/kudos", user_id: user.get("id"), authenticity_token: token)
    .done((data, status) ->
      kudosLeft = self.get 'controllers.currentUser.kudosLeft'
      if kudosLeft > 0
        self.decrementProperty "controllers.currentUser.kudosLeft" 
      else 
        $flashContainer.empty()
        jQuery(ErrorMessageTmplt).appendTo($flashContainer).show()
    )
    .fail((data, status) ->
        $flashContainer.empty()
        jQuery(ErrorMessageTmplt).appendTo($flashContainer).show()
    )
```

I think it should be rendered somewhere in the application template but I don't know how. Maybe the alert should be a partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the alert html to your application template:

```
<div id="flash" class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

And then for each action, you can call jQuery and fill the span with a [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or an [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), like this:

```
App.ProductRemoveRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var c = this.controllerFor('product');
        controller.set('content', c.get('content'));
    },
    events: {
        confirmRemove: function(record) {
            record.deleteRecord();

            // I know this looks no good, and definitely has 
            // room for improvement but gets the flash going
            $("#flash span").text("Product successfully removed.")
            .show().parent().fadeIn()
            .delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function() { 
                $("#flash span").text('') 
            });

            this.transitionTo('products');
        }
    }
});
```

You might want to add that div as a hidden element or you can use Ember's View [`didInsertElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) to hide it:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$('#flash').hide();
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/aMGFC/ (Old)

http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/FYvuD/ (New)

As of this new sample, I'm using a dummy mixin to erase the notification text, which is now in a property in `ApplicationController` and the notification flash is a partial view template.

This obviously not the only way to go about it and it's more of a experimentation/sample of what one could do in order to flash a notification message. Again, I'm sure this could be implemented in a more elegant and modular way. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one additional question. Why didn't you handle actions like 'remove' ine the controller but instead sent it to the route? Is it an Ember convention? Where can I more read about it?

Comment: @Wojtek'rrh'Ryrych That doesn't have to be handled in the route, could have been done in the controller with no problems, I just wanted to transition right away after deleting the record, although I could have used `this.get('target').transitionTo('some.route')` in the controller as well. It's a matter of choice really. You can read more about the events [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_target-bubbling). Just be consistent in your app as to where you handle the events.